# Unable to install CentOS in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I am trying to install CentOS 5.6 in My VirtualBox but i got this error on boot screen.

`Your CPU Does not support long mode : use a 32 bit Distribution`

My CPU is 64 bit i checked that using `uname -a' command and the output is

`Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.43.8-1.fc15.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 4 20:33:44 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

As per my knowledge i need to enable 32 bit support to my VirtualBox but i don't from where i can enable that.

If you have any idea regarding this then please suggest me.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: [See here](http://blog.nexcess.net/2012/07/19/64-bit-centos-installing-32-bit-packages/)

Comment: Thanks,but i am trying to run 64 bit OS in my 64 bit system

Comment: [More info](http://www.secure-eserver.com/?p=359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently both VMware (in VMplayer 5 and VMware workstation 9) and Oracle Virtual Box require that you have VT extensions enabled in your computer BIOS for 64-bit support to work.

From Wikipedia: VirtualBox supports some guests (including 64-bit guests, SMP guests and certain proprietary OSs) only on hosts with hardware-assisted virtualization.

In other words, make sure you have VT extensions enabled in your BIOS, and it should work.

**EDIT:** If you are not sure if your system even supports hardware assisted virtualization, this is how to check:

1. Windows: install and run [HAV detection tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592)
2. Linux: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and check for `vmx` (Intel VT) or `svm` (AMD SVM)
   flags. If you don't see them, your hardware is too old.

Comment: can you give me a link to enable virtualization?

Comment: Reboot your computer and hit F1/F2/Del (it depends on your computer model) to get into BIOS. Look around for option called VT, VT-x, hardware virtualization or something like that and enable it. Save and quit from BIOS - you're done!

Comment: yeah i did the same but seems Virtulization is not supported by my system because i didn't found such option. here is my [cpuinfo](http://pastie.org/5175550)

Comment: I guess you now have excuse to get new computer :-)